# $X_1,X_2$ distributed $U(0,1)$ and independent, find the distribution of $D=|X_2-X_1|$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know it shouldn't be this hard but I am having trouble anyway.
I tried using $F_D(t)=\mathbb{P}(|X_2-X_1|\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(-t\leq X_1-X_2\leq t)$ and sketching the unit square $[0,1]^2$ but to no avail, I can't seem to find a formula that fits.

Comment: you already sketched the square. Try to plot the extreme conditions $|X_1-X_2| = t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the pink area in this unit square?

[image: added enter image description here]

Comment: I think I get it, I should treat one of the X's as the y coordinate, draw the lines $X_2=X_1-t$ and $X_2=t-X_1$ and treat the area according to the $\geq$ or $\leq$, which then gives me the whole area of the square (1) minus the area in pink? Which then coincides with @tommik 's answer

Comment: Yes, though the second line is $X_2=X_1+t$

Comment: Yes my bad thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you to a drawing of the problem it will be very easy to find

$$F_D(d)=1-(1-d)^2$$

and derivating you get the density

$$f_D(d)=2(1-d)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0;1]}(d)$$

---

[image]

The CDF is the white area, in function of $d \in [0;1]$
To calculate it, it is easier to calculate the purple area $(1-d)^2$ and take the complement to 1

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch for the solution:** setting $Z:=(X,Y)$ you will have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr [|X-Y|\leqslant c]&=\Pr [Z\in A_c]\\&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{A_c}(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y)\mathop{}\!d (x,y)\\
&=\int_{[0,1]^2}\mathbf{1}_{A_c}(x,y)\mathop{}\!d (x,y)
\end{align*}
$$
where $A_c:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x-y|\leqslant c\}$ and $f_X(t)=f_Y(t)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(t)$ are the densities of $X$ and $Y$. Now observe that

$$
\mathbf{1}_{A_c}(x,y)=1 \iff |x-y|\leqslant c \iff x-y\in[-c,c]\iff y\in \mathbb{R}\,\land\, x\in [y-c,y+c]
$$

Therefore $\mathbf{1}_{A_c}(x,y)=\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}}(y)\mathbf{1}_{[y-c,y+c]}(x)$, and so substituting in the last integral we find that

$$
Pr[|X-Y|\leqslant c]=\int_0^{1}\int_0^{1}\mathbf{1}_{[y-c,y+c]}(x)\mathop{}\!d x\mathop{}\!d y
$$

Now the inner integral is just the Lebesgue measure of the set $[0,1]\cap [y-c,y+c]$, this is $1-(y-c)$ when $y-c\in[0,1]$ or $y+c$ when $y+c\in[0,1]$, therefore

$$
Pr[|X-Y|\leqslant c]=\int_0^{1}((1-y+c)\mathbf{1}_{[c,c+1]}(y)+(y+c)\mathbf{1}_{[-c,1-c]}(y))\mathop{}\!d y
$$